# kubectl replace -f says it has replaces a resource, but it actually hasn't

Tags: shell, kubernetes, sh, kubectl

I am writing a shell script to create and tear down a persistent volume and a persistent volume claim. While tearing down, I have to get into the persistent volume claim resource and delete the finalizer limitation, using

```
kubectl get pvc example-pvc -o yaml > hype.yaml && \
sed -i '/^[^#]*finalizer/c\' hype.yaml && \
sed -i '/^[^#]*pvc-protection/c\' hype.yaml && \
kubectl replace pvc example-pvc -o yaml -f hype.yaml.
```

The `hype.yaml` file does not carry the limitation anymore,

```
persistentvolumeclaim/example-pvc replaced
```

is displayed, but the resource itself, as indicated through `kubectl edit pvc example-pvc`, is unchanged and thus refuses to tear down the persistent volume claim.

Any idea why this is and how to fix it?

On @Kamol Hasan's request:

```
$kubectl get pvc 
NAME         STATUS        VOLUME      CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
example-pvc   Terminating   example-pv   10Gi       RWX
```

The second requested command yields a very long .yaml file, but, as I said, where the finalizer lines are absent.

Comment: Can you also provide the output of `kubectl get pvc` & `kubectl get pvc example-pvc -o yaml` ?

Comment: @Kamol Hasan: Tried to comply with your request.

Comment: I was asking because you're replacing `example-pvc`, but why it showing `fabric-pvc` replaced.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change all my output.

Comment: Have you tried adding `--force` flag to `kubectl replace`?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and learn yq (from https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/) to edit your yamls: 
`kubectl get pvc example-pvc -o yaml | yq 'del .metadata.finalizers' | kubectl replace -f -`
:-)

Answer (score 0):

If your PVC is attached to a PV, then it won't terminate unless your PV is also terminated. It will be stuck in that terminating state forever. Update the PV, then update the PVC. You could simply put the PV and PVC in the same yaml and run `kubectl apply -f`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is the other way around, i. e. one first has to delete the pvc and is, only then, able to delete the pv. Anyway, my question pertains more to the conflicting phenomena, i. e. confirming replacement, but displaying unchangedness.